# How to change the name of each file that receives emailJS?

Tags: typescript, email, email-attachments

I have a function in typescript in which I use the emailJS service, in this function I send an array of files converted to base64, this works correctly but I would like to assign each file a name.

I tried to send an object in which I had the content of the base64 and a filename but in this way it does not send any file.

```
import { encode } from 'base64-arraybuffer';
import * as emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

const service = '...';
const templateInvoice = '...';
const templateAssignment = '...';
const userId = '...';

export const sendInvoiceEmail = (invoiceId: string, to_: string[], from_: string, attachments: any[]) => {

    const attachmentsBase64 = [];

    attachments.forEach(element => {
      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(element.file);
      const base64String = encode(uint8Array);
      attachmentsBase64.push({ filename: element.name, content: base64String}):
    });
  
    const message = {
      to: to_,
      from: from_,
      invoice_id : invoiceId,
      attachment: attachmentsBase64
    };

    return emailjs
        .send(
            service,
            templateInvoice,
            message,
            userId
        )
}
```